# Mongo regex pattern syntax match slash

Tags: regex, mongodb

I'm trying to search for urls that start with a certain format, e.g. `http://stackoverflow.com/questions` using the mongo pattern syntax. I've tried

```
db.mycollection.find({"link": /^http://stackoverflow.com/questions/})
```

which obviously didn't work because the `/` character is a delimiter. I've also tried escaping slashes with backslashes:

```
db.mycollection.find({"link": /^http:\/\/stackoverflow\.com\/questions/})
```

but that gave me a syntax error. So how do I match slashes?

Comment: Missing `)` at the end in `db.mycollection.find({"link": /^http:\/\/stackoverflow\.com\/questions/}`?

Comment: Try using `db.mycollection.find({link:{'$regex' : '^http://stackoverflow[.]com/questions'}})`.

Comment: @Tushar thanks, but that was only in the question.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that escaping slashes with backslashes only doesn't work in [MongoHub](https://github.com/jeromelebel/MongoHub-Mac). It works as expected in the console, i.e.

```
db.mycollection.find({"link": /^http:\/\/stackoverflow\.com\/questions/})
```

Comment: Did you try using the constructor notation (`new RegExp("http://stackoverflow[.]com/questions")` instead of `/^http:\/\/stackoverflow\.com\/questions/`) in MongoHub? In a constructor notation, you do not have to escape forward slashes.